# Mordell-Weil rank in elliptic surfaces

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Suppose that an elliptic smooth K3 surface $X$ defined over a number field $k$ has arithmetic Picard rank $r$ and assume that it is equipped with a $k$ fibration over $\mathbb{P}^1$ that has a section over $k$, i.e. $f:X\to \mathbb{P}^1$ is a dominant map with the generic fiber $f^{-1}(\eta)$ being an elliptic curve. Is there a relation between the Mordell-Weil rank of the generic fiber and $r$ ?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you know the answer in case $k$ is instead something  algebraically closed?

Comment: No, not really:(

Comment: OK, let me try to write something that applies in that case, and then maybe you can see how to adapt it to your setting...

Comment: Maybe just an explicit example would be ok ?

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are looking for the Shioda-Tate formula. See Corollary VII.2.4 in page 70 of Miranda's "[The basic theory of elliptic surfaces](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~miranda/BTES-Miranda.pdf)", or [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=mwBP2G1TOmUC&pg=PA254&lpg=PA254&dq=shioda%20tate%20formula&source=bl&ots=oN2UC9Fs2J&sig=dwDIExXKJHp7JVSvmz1SNlCHD3I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bpxFVZ3OJIKagwS6goGQDQ&ved=0CFsQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=shioda%20tate%20formula&f=false).

Note: let $k$ be a
field and let $C/k$ be a smooth projective curve defined over the
field $k$ and has genus $g$. The function field of $C/k$ will be
denoted by $K=k(C)$. An elliptic surface $\mathcal{E}$ over the curve $C$
is, by definition, a two-dimensional projective variety together
with (*i*) a morphism $\pi: \mathcal{E} \to C$ such that for all but
finitely many points $t\in C(\overline{k})$, the fiber
$\mathcal{E}_t=\pi^{-1}(t)$ is a non-singular curve of genus $1$, and (*ii*) a section to $\pi$ (the *zero section*) $\sigma_0: C \to
\mathcal{E}$. With this
definition, the generic fibre of $\pi$, $E/K$, may be regarded as
an elliptic curve over the field $K$.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation on why the rank of the rank of E(K) is the rank of the generic mordell weil rank please?

Comment: I added a note to the answer, since it was too long for a comment. The E/K that appears in the note is the E/K that appears in the Shioda-Tate formula.

Comment: See also Section 4.4 in http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/bouyer/first_year_report.pdf

Comment: See also https://www.rug.nl/research/portal/files/9770516/c4.pdf

Comment: @CaptainDarling was this somehow not what you were looking for?

Comment: getting anxious ?

Comment: I'm not after fake internet points. I was really asking whether you had a more specific relationship in mind. Didn't you at some point ask something specific about the Fermat quartic or some other surface?

Comment: Indeed. Any ideas on what the degenerate fibers are here ? Or a reference ?

Comment: Shioda-Tate gives that the Mordell-Weil rank is $14$ owing to the Picard rank being $20$ and the existence of exactly $4$ degenerate fibers-each of which having $2$ components defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Do you find the same ?

Comment: I did some experiments with magma...most of the elliptic curves fibers have MW rank no equal to $14$ as your answer suggest...500 points for nothing after all...

Comment: My answer here only points out the Shioda-Tate formula, which is indeed a relation between the Picard rank and the Mordell-Weil rank of E(K). That's all.

Comment: Yeah, thanks...